# Wordpress eclass

Tags: wordpress, file-manager

I have an assignment to create a sort of eclass within wordpress. Special users (ie teachers) should be able to upload slides etc from the frontend and they should appear on the site, in designated sections. That should not be too hard, but I am a beginner - should I use a filemanager plugin for that? or an uploader plugin ? everything should be doable from the frontend and I dont want to invest time using a plugin only to find out I cant realy do everything that I want - ie I want teachers to have a way to manage the files from the frontend.

So, suggestions for plugins are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider http://www.7tech.co.in/wordpress/file-manager-plugin-for-wordpress/ plugin also
It is easy to use, full ajax based.
Similar like cpanel file manager